# In a glass prism why is is the angle of incidence NOT EQUAL to the angle of refraction

Tags: optics

In a glass prism why is is the angle of incidence NOT EQUAL to the angle of refraction....
Now i know that inclined surfaces come into play but is that only for a ray grazing the surface of the prism, the aforesaid prism will have a angle of incidence equal to angle of refraction.

Comment: Can you please add a diagram to help us better understand what do you mean?

Comment: I think the answer could be "Snell's law" (you can google it), but I want to be sure of having interpreted it right

Comment: A diagram is necessary.  The angle of incidence is never equal to the angle of refraction, prism or not.   I don't understand the question, and a diagram will sort things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the wave does not remain in a single medium and face a uniform resistance.

Consider water waves as an analogy of light waves, when water waves flow onto a lesser depth suddenly, there is a different quantity of water being raised and lowered by the same quantity of energy.  The energy needed to move in one the forward direction has reduced, and that spent along the wave-front has not. So the waves are turned *proportionally to that change in resistance* in order for  momentum to be conserved.

Likewise light waves changing from one medium to the other are affected proportionally to the change in resistance (i.e. [the optical index / index of refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index)) as well.  Since this index represents how a medium slows light, (although this happens for different reasons than those that depth, mass or density slow water waves) the direction of the light must similarly adjust when it becomes harder or easier to propagate.  Otherwise the light would not be equally slowed along both axes in the plane through which the wave propagates.

If the rule were determined entirely by the angle of incidence, there would be no place for this proportional effect, and the speed of propagation could not be equally limited in both directions.

Instead, [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell's_law) applies: the new angle has the sine value proportional to the incidence angle's sine value as the new resistance is to the old one.

Comment: This is an interesting point of view and analogy, and it has some merit.  However, I don't see a way to give physical meaning to *resistance* in the context of the propagation of light.  On that account, this description might cause misunderstanding or confusion if the analogy is taken too literally.

Comment: very correct  the word resistance is creating much confusion

Comment: @garyp  Added a reference to the specific physical meaning intended by 'resistance' in optics.  It is in fact not hard to give at all.